# how to call a mouse event to dom object that lies behind other in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-events

I want to call a mousemove js event to a dom object that are behind other, how can I call the event ignoring the front object?

I want to call a rect draw, I made them with js and divs, first I have the root div that is my height and width ref, then want to use mouse events to resize and re-positioning a 'rect' div, the problem is when I call mousemove event to my 'root' to get the mouse position data and my rect lies in front then the calc is gone crazy, I did mean, the 'root'.mousemove event is cancelled when my mouse reach the 'rect' object, so I want to set my rect to be 'transparent' and then use just my 'root' event handlers, hope you can understand and help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
            <div id="rect">

            </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var root = document.getElementById('root');
        var rect =document.getElementById('rect');

        root.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            rect.style.width = e.offsetX;
            rect.style.height = e.offsetY;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make 'rect' to be 'transparent' for js mouse events.

Comment: Summary Approach I would Take: I think you want to handle the mouse move at the document level only, then collect your element positions in an array, then check for any mouse coordinate collisions within that event, in that collision logic find the bottom most item if there is more than 1, operate on that item as needed.

Comment: I think your event handler should use event bubbling concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample JS fiddle sample ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/dk2rL3b0)). This is working fine. As you move the mouse, the height and width of the inner rect would change. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div id="root" style="border:1px solid red; height: 100px; width: 100%;">
        <div id="rect" style="border:1px solid gray; min-height: 20px; min-width:10px; margin: 5px;">
        </div>
</div>
<script>
    var root = document.getElementById('root');
    var rect =document.getElementById('rect');

    root.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
        rect.style.width = e.offsetX + "px";
        rect.style.height = e.offsetY + "px";
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is working for you, please mark as answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out my problem, the easy way to do it is set pointer-events: none; in "rect".css attribute,
    or create new one css selector:

```
.rect.scaling{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```